# How in javascript to convert a date to a specific format

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how can I convert with a library or pure JS a date like this

`Fri Mar 05 2021 13:51:35 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)`

to this format

`2021-03-05 13:51:35.829058+00`

As asked in comments what I was trying to achieve is to convert the shared date to specific format I tried the following stuff

```
1) const t = createdAt
      .toISOString()
      .replace('T', ' ')
      .replace('Z', '');
2) Using date-fns
format(addMinutes(date, date.getTimezoneOffset()), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

The result of those tries is like

`2021-03-05 14:44:11`

But is not correct as I need after 11 more numbers and +00.

Comment: Probably because this has been answered so many times on SO already, and doesn't indicate what you have tried.

Comment: I already saw many ways of format but now one helped me.
I used date-fns and moment. 
The issue is that the last part is not formatted as 00.0000+00 I have no idea what to use to have it right

Comment: `I already saw many ways of format but now one helped me`  There is no indication of that in the question, at all. What have you tried?  What didn't work?  How did you try date-fns and moment?  Show us some code.  This is not answerable as is.

Comment: I can recommend MomentJS, you can do almost anything with it, as long as you pass a valid date

Comment: Can you show me an example because the issue still with moment is to have in the exact forma I need I can have it as same of date-fns bt cannot have the last part as mentioned din my question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use **UTCDate()**, you need have a full date to get all items:

```
function pad(e){ return (e.toString().length<2?'0'+e:e); }

function ShowData(data){ var d = new Date(data); return d.getFullYear()+'-'+pad(d.getMonth()+1) +'-'+ pad(d.getDate())+' '+pad(d.getHours())+':'+pad(d.getMinutes())+':'+pad(d.getSeconds())+'.'+pad(d.getMilliseconds())+pad(d.getUTCDate())+"+00"; }
```

When you use your example:

```
ShowData('Fri Mar 05 2021 13:51:35 GMT+0000');
```

Then you got

> 2021-03-05 10:51:35.0005+00

When we use a full date form:

```
ShowData(new Date());
```

Then you got

> 2021-03-05 13:05:36.51605+00

I hope could help.